# What is psychotropic music?

Tags: history, health, styles

I hit the term `psychotropic music` and listened to some works but was surprised that this music style has no good description on the internet (its origin, history, goal, etc.).

When googling you will get a lot of commercial websites and there's article on Wikipedia neither.

Do you know where to get more knowledge and could you write a few sentences about it?

(please help me with tags of this topic)

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Psychotropic* means mind-altering. The most common use of the word is in *psychotropic drugs* -- that is drugs which alter mood, perception, consciousness and behaviour.

*Psychotropic Music* is a term used by some people to describe music which they believe alters mood, perception, consciousness and behaviour in a similar way to such drugs. It's likely that people use the drugs and the music together.

I don't believe there's a broadly accepted definition of what kind of music that is. It would apply just as well to tribal drumming, 1970s Space Rock, acid house, electronic trance and ambient music.

I suspect that modern day proponents of the name are making electronic ambient / trance music.

Comment: +1, I do seem to recall it being mostly used in the nineties in the context of Sativa type drummers - an ecstatic community drumming which was supposed to create a state of something :-)

Comment: @slim OK, I accept your answer, but more info and information sources is welcome. I have listened to [Boris Mourashkin](http://www.myspace.com/borismourashkin) which seems to be the main artist of this style.

Comment: Well, that's the most grudging super-fast accept I've had. You can always wait a couple of days to see if you get a better answer.

Comment: @slim, some of us are impatien